# Why doesn't QLabel.setFocus() pass focus to the next widget?

Tags: qt5, focus, pyside2, qlabel

When I `TAB` around a form with labels and line edits I don't see `QLabel`s getting any focus; the focus rightly passes to the line edit next to it i.e. to the `QWidget` that is `label.nextInFocusChain()`.

What I originally want: in a `QLineEdit.editingFinished`'s slot I want to set focus to the next (in TAB order) line edit.  I do `self.sender().nextInFocusChain().setFocus()`; instead of a line edit, its label, the one next in focus chain, gets focus.

When `QLabel.setFocus()` is called, focus is on the label itself; doing another `TAB` sets the focus to the expected line edit after it.  Why is this the case?  Why isn't the focus not set to the widget after it?  Why is the focus not set  like the `TAB` key does?

I checked the focus policy of the labels; they `Qt.NoFocus` (default).  I also set the `textInteractionFlags` of the label to `Qt.NoTextInteraction` in vain.

Setting the line edit as the label's focus-proxy does what I want, but I'm not convinced this is the correct solution; or there's a gap in my understanding.

## Minimal Example

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLineEdit, QWidget, \
    QFormLayout, QPushButton, QMainWindow, QLabel
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        txtName = QLineEdit('')
        txtAge = QLineEdit('')
        self.lblAge = QLabel('&Age')
        self.lblAge.setBuddy(txtAge)
        # This or (default) Qt.LinksAccessibleByMouse doesn't help.
        # self.lblAge.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.NoTextInteraction)
        btnNext = QPushButton('N&ext')
        btnNext.clicked.connect(self.moveFocus)
        formLayout = QFormLayout()
        formLayout.addRow('&Name', txtName)
        formLayout.addRow(self.lblAge, txtAge)
        formLayout.addRow(btnNext)
        window = QWidget()
        window.setLayout(formLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(window)

    def moveFocus(self):
        self.lblAge.setFocus()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

I'm on ArchLinux with Xfce4 desktop environment using Qt5's official Python bindings i.e. PySide2.

Comment: It would seem logic dictates that a widget with a `NoFocus` policy must be able to receive programmatic focus, otherwise it could never participate in a focus-proxy relation. Although the docs don't spell it out, [Qt.FocusPolicy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#FocusPolicy-enum) only controls *user interaction* - there are no options for explicitly controlling any of the other ways in which a widget can receive focus (see e.g. [Qt.FocusReason](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#FocusReason-enum)). So it would appear that setting a proxy is a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The focus policy of widgets only tells whether the widget will accept focus after user interaction; in fact, the documentation says, for example, that "the widget accepts keyboard focus **by tabbing**" or "**by clicking**".

When a label is set for a buddy it doesn't mean that it can get focus, nor that it's part of the focus chain, and neither it will set the focus on that buddy when it actually receives it (programmatically or not): the only purpose of the buddy feature is to set the focus on the buddy when *its shortcut* is triggered.

Calling `setFocus()` explicitly, though, will always make the widget get focus, even if its policy is `NoFocus`, and that's because the call has been done *programmatically*, and it didn't get the focus from user interaction. Plus, the widget *must* be able to receive a focus in event, even if it ignores it, and that's exactly how focus proxies work.

In fact, when focus is changed by user interaction (including window activation), Qt does not call `setFocus()` at all; instead, it sends a QFocusEvent to the target widget, which would eventually be propagated to the parent(s) in the object tree.

It's unclear why you're trying to set the focus based on the label, but if you *really* need to do that, then you have the following options:

- set a focus proxy, as you already found out;
- in the function that should set focus, check if the widget is a QLabel and if it has a buddy that accepts focus, then use `setFocus()` for that;
- subclass QLabel, override `focusInEvent()`, and do the above;

With the subclass approach you can even override the `mousePressEvent` handler so that when the user clicks the label, it will automatically set the focus on the buddy.

The same can be done by setting the widget as focus proxy of the label and then setting the focus policy of the label to `ClickFocus`.

Comment: I see we've a [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) here :) _It's unclear why you're trying to set the focus based on the label_. Well, I'm actually in a `QLineEdit.editingFinished`'s slot where I want to set focus to the next line edit, so I do `self.sender().nextInFocusChain().setFocus()` and instead of the line edit, its label, the one next in focus chain, gets focus.

Comment: @legends2k A small correction on my answer: all widgets are in the focus chain, but they can only *get* user focus if their policy allows it, if not, Qt goes on to the next (assuming it's not the original widget). That said, you can do the same with a basic loop: `nextWidget = self.sender().nextInFocusChain()` `while not nextWidget.focusPolicy() & Qt.StrongFocus:` `nextWidget = nextWidget.nextInFocusChain()`.

Comment: I worked out the loop solution myself but thought there's a better way.  Thanks for your answer; it clears up a few gaps in my understanding.